# Despite passing an rvalue, why isn't my move constructor getting called?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics, move-constructor

I create a class string by defining default, copy & move constructor. I try to create objects expecting each constructor to be invoked. As expected, the default & copy constructor are invoked, but when I pass a rvalue(temporary object), I still see move constructor NOT being invoked.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

class string
{
    char * data;
public:
    string(const char * p = nullptr)
    {
        if(p == nullptr) return;
        std::cout << "string(const char * p)" << std::endl;
        size_t size = strlen(p) + 1;
        data = new char[size];
        memcpy(data, p, size);
    }
    ~string()
    {
        std::cout << "~string() - " << data << std::endl;
        delete[] data;
    }
    string(const string & that)
    {
        std::cout << "string(const string &)" << std::endl;
        size_t size = strlen(that.data) + 1;
        data = new char[size];
        memcpy(data, that.data, size);
    }
    string(string && that)
    {
        std::cout << "string(string && )" << std::endl;
        data = that.data;
        that.data = nullptr;
    }
    void showData() { std::cout << data << std::endl; }
    string operator+(const string & other)
    {
        size_t datasize = strlen(data);
        size_t othersize = strlen(other.data);
        size_t totalsize = datasize + othersize + 1;
        char * sData = new char[totalsize];
        memcpy(sData, data, strlen(data));
        memcpy(sData+datasize, other.data, totalsize-datasize);
        string s(sData);
        delete[] sData;
        return s;

    }
    string & operator=(string that)
    {
        char * tmp = data;
        data = that.data;
        that.data = tmp;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    string s1{"stackoverflow"};  // s1
    string s2{s1};               // s2
    string s3{string("stack")+string("exchange")};  // s3
}
```

At **s1**: *default constructor* is being called as expected.

At **s2**: *copy constructor* is invoked, also as expected.

At **s3**: I'm passing a temporary object. So, I expect *move constructor* be invoked, but *default constructor* being called.

I'm unable to comprehend what I'm missing. Kindly help, thanks.

Comment: Which compiler? I see it being called, but suspect UB

Comment: Compiled it from https://wandbox.org/ with gcc HEAD 10.0.0 20190 &  clang HEAD 9.0.0.

Comment: Here `string s3{string("stack")+string("exchange")};  // s3` default constructor is being call 3 times: `string("stack")`, `string("exchange")`, and in `operator+` at line `string s(sData)`. And as doctorlove mentioned, because of UB, move constructor just hadn't been executed yet

Comment: `s3` is a case where compilers are allowed to *elide* the move constructor (and one matching destructor). Search for "C++ copy elision" for several articles explaining.

Comment: Not related to the question: The default constructor needs to set `data` to `nullptr` if the argument is a null pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it behaves as you say with GCC and Clang, but the move constructor is called with VC++. Looks like a bug, then you should move explicitly with std::move().

Comment: Not a bug (even if the print of nullptr in the destructor is fixed): this is a case where compilers are optionally allowed to elide the move constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You have defined `data` as a `char *`.

```
string(string && that)
{
    std::cout << "string(string && )" << std::endl;
    data = that.data;
    that.data = nullptr;
}
```

means that the "copy" of `data` in the move constructor isn't a deep copy.

*Edit: Now, that would be ok, since you can "gut" the rvalue, however, when it destructors you do this using a `nullptr`:*

When you call

```
std::cout << "~string() - " << data << std::endl;
```

in the destructor, data is null, you have undefined behaviour. Anything could happen.

Comment: I believe move constructor endorses to use/grab the memory of the parameter/argument. So is the reason for shallow copy.

I thought assigning "that.data = nullptr" will not call destructor for "that" parameter/argument. So, where do you see undefined behavior?

Comment: The deep/shallow copy point possibly doesn't help. Printing  `that.data` (which is nullptr) when the `that` destructor happens is UB though. (Been more explicit in an edit)